# Magento 2.2.5: Idea about delete "Banner_Slide"

Tags: magento2, delete, banner-slider

i'm doing "Banner Slider" and looking for how to delete column in `banner_slide`. Its hard to explain. So just look in my example:

So this is what i've done til now. A banner which contain 3 slide.

[image]

What i want is when i click in that checkbox to turn off the choose, it will count and render through HTML and then when i click `Save Banner` or `Save and Continue Edit`, it will delete columns in `banner_slide` table in Mysql that have checkbox turning off.

So i'm following the `catalog_category_products` in magento 2. And what they do is look like this:
[image]
Like you can see, it render into HTML like i said.

And when i click on `Save Banner` button, it will run into `Controller/../Save.php` and save data to `banner_slide` table in Mysql.

So here is the Save.php:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Manage\Save.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Administrator
 * Date: 20/07/2018
 * Time: 4:15 CH
 */

namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Manage;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Aht\BannerSlider\Model\BannerFactory;
use Aht\BannerSlider\Model\BannerSlideFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $bannerFactory;

    protected $bannerSlideFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        BannerFactory $bannerFactory,
        BannerSlideFactory $bannerSlideFactory
    ) {
        $this->bannerFactory = $bannerFactory;
        $this->bannerSlideFactory = $bannerSlideFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
//
        if ($data) {
            try{
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                $banner = $this->bannerFactory->create();

                if(isset($data['banner_slide'])){
//                    lấy chuỗi json banner_slide được truyền vào từ form HTML.
                    $slide = json_decode($data['banner_slide'], true);
                    foreach($slide as $key => $value){
                        $bannerSlide = $this->bannerSlideFactory->create();

//                        check xem banner_slider này đã tồn tại hay chưa, nếu tồn tại thì không insert vào db.
                        $check = $bannerSlide->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('banner_id',$id)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('slide_id',$key)
                            ->getSize();
                        if($check = 0){
                            $bannerSlide->setBannerId($id);
                            $bannerSlide->setSlideId($key);
                            $bannerSlide->setPosition($value);
                            $bannerSlide->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($id){
                    $banner->load($id);
                    $data['id'] = $id;
                }
                $banner->setData($data);
                $banner->save();

                if ($id) {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Update Banner Successfully.'));
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Add Banner Successfully.'));
                }

//              check for Save and Continue Edit Button
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/detail', ['id' => $banner->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                } else {
                    $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
                }

                return $resultRedirect;
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my banner_slide table:
[image]

I can save into the database through foreach loop successfully the `banner_slide` which "checkbox" turning on, but i dont know how to do that with `banner_slide` which turning off. So i need an idea on how to do that...

Thanks for reading. Have a good day :)

EDIT 1:

So i've found 2 way to do this:

1. Delete all the record in table and then insert again.
2. Select all the record in table and compare with the json banner_slide, and what doesn't have in json will be delete.

But what if i have 1000 record in the table? So these 2 way are not really good.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code to your **Grid.php**:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('id');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
        'delete',
        array(
            'label' => __('Delete'),
            'url' => $this->getUrl('banner/*/massDelete'),
            'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
        )
    );
    return $this;
}
```

Also create Delete.php controller and the below code under your module like below path:

> app/code/Vendor/Banner/Controller/Adminhtml/Banner/Delete.php

Code for **Delete.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\Banner;

class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {

         $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if (!is_array($ids) || empty($ids)) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please select product(s).'));
        } else {
            try {
                foreach ($ids as $id) {
                    $row = $this->_objectManager->get('Vendor\Banner\Model\Banner')->load($id);
                    $row->delete();
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', count($ids))
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
         $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

You need to change the Vendor and Module name according to your requirement.

Comment: hold up, so where exactly this massActionDelete should render in HTML?

Comment: if it render a Delete Action button, so i dont need it, because what i want is click the checkbox and then click "Save" button .

Comment: Just above your grid.

Comment: Mass action will show as a dropdown. from there you can select delete option and submit then all the selected banners will be deleted.

Comment: Yes i can see that, but that's not what i'm looking for .. @@ The goal here is when i click "save" , then it will delete what doesn't turn on in the checkbox.

Comment: Not clear. You need to delete when click save? What do you mean? Can you add how do you want in screenshot?

Comment: Hmmm .. yes, i want to delete when i click save, i mean which banner_slide that doesn't turning on in the check box is remove from table "banner_slide" when i click "save".

Comment: For example: right now i have 3 banner_slide just like in the first picture, okay?
Then i click on check box of the slide_3 which have "slide_id" = 3. After that, i click save,  and call to Save.php, in that, i want to delete the column that have slide_id = 3.
That's all.

Comment: But ofcouse it have to be more than 1 column to be deleted. Which mean i can delete 2 column at the same time. For example, i can unclick in checkbox "slide_3" and "slide_2", so it will delete slide_3 and slide_2.